# How to use chartjs-plugin-datalabels for specific charts using vue-chart.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chart.js, vue-chartjs

I'm trying to use **chartjs-plugin-datalables** for specific charts using **vue-chartjs**. So firstly i have unregistered the plugin globally from my main.js file as it is registered globally when imported.

```
import Chart from 'chart.js';
import ChartDataLabels from 'chartjs-plugin-datalabels';

Chart.defaults.global.plugins.datalabels.display = false;
```

Then i'm adding the plugin for specific chart. But no labels are showing.

```
import { Pie } from "vue-chartjs";
import ChartDataLabels from "chartjs-plugin-datalabels";
export default {
    extends: Pie,
    methods: {
        intChart() {
            var _this = this;
            this.renderChart({
                ..........       
            });
        }
    },

    mounted() {
        this.addPlugin(ChartDataLabels);
        this.intChart();
    }
};
```

If i disable the following line it works for all the charts.

```
Chart.defaults.global.plugins.datalabels.display = false;
```

Any idea why isn't it working for specific charts?

Comment: Is the `addPlugin` method in your code? Then show it

Comment: No. This is a library function of **vue-chartjs**. Btw i have got the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disable the **chartjs-plugin-datalabels** globally i had to use

```
Chart.plugins.unregister(ChartDataLabels);
```

instead of

```
Chart.defaults.global.plugins.datalabels.display = false;
```

in my main.js file. Then `addPlugin` function works perfectly.

Comment: Could you please share your `addPlugin` function code ? Thanks